# Python - Exception unhandled "name 'main' is not defined"

Tags: python, sql-server, etl

I am currently learning python and would like some assistance.

I am unsure where the syntax is incorrect. It states "name 'main' is not defined"

I have seen other examples where the syntax looks the same but for some reason mine is not working.

```
 class Main(main):
    """description of class"""

    def main():
      print('starting etl')
      # establish connection for target database (sql-server)
      target_cnx = pyodbc.connect(**datawarehouse_db_config)    
      # loop through credentials

      # sql-server
      for config in sqlserver_db_config: 
        try:
          print("loading db: " + config['database'])
          etl_process(sqlserver_queries, target_cnx, config, 'sqlserver')
        except Exception as error:
          print("etl for {} has error".format(config['database']))
          print('error message: {}'.format(error))
          continue
      target_cnx.close()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Take everything inside the class, move it out of the class, and delete the class. All that stuff should not be in a class.

Comment: Great, thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Your class `Main` tries to inherit from non-existent class `main`.

`main` is only defined as a method of class `Main`.

Looks like you only wanted to have a function `main` without the class `Main`.

```
def main():
  print('starting etl')
  # establish connection for target database (sql-server)
  target_cnx = pyodbc.connect(**datawarehouse_db_config)    
  # loop through credentials

  # sql-server
  for config in sqlserver_db_config: 
    try:
      print("loading db: " + config['database'])
      etl_process(sqlserver_queries, target_cnx, config, 'sqlserver')
    except Exception as error:
      print("etl for {} has error".format(config['database']))
      print('error message: {}'.format(error))
      continue
  target_cnx.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```